# R - How to perform list-column operations in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with a data table that has a nested data table stored in a column:

```
   fertName.x YDRange.x fertName.y YDRange.y               dat
1:      fertA     36-80      fertB     36-80 <data.table[7x3]>
2:      fertA     36-80      fertC     36-80 <data.table[7x3]>
3:      fertA     36-80      fertD     36-80 <data.table[7x3]>
```

where the `dat` column of the first row looks like this:

```
   FIELD_uniqueName OBS_numValue.x OBS_numValue.y
1:           fieldA              5              3
2:           fieldB              4              5
3:           fieldC              7              5
4:           fieldD              5              5
5:           fieldE              4              5
6:           fieldF              4              4
7:           fieldG              5              7
```

For each row of the main data table, I need to do create a few new columns that will be based off calculations done on the values of the nested data table.

Three examples of such new columns would be:

```
n = .N, # count of rows of the nested data table,
vari = var(OBS_Value.x - OBS_Value.y), # variance of observed values
pvalue = t.test(OBS_Value.x - OBS_Value.y, conf.level = 0.90)$p.value  # p-value from t test of observations
```

My real table has over 10 million rows, so the solution needs to be fast and with a relatively low memory footprint.

The expected result would be:

```
   fertName.x YDRange.x fertName.y YDRange.y               dat n     vari pvalue
1:      fertA     36-80      fertB     36-80 <data.table[7x3]> 7 2.333333      1
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Steps to reproduce an example dataset:

```
library(data.table)

# main data table
dt <- "fertName.x YDRange.x fertName.y YDRange.y
fertA 36-80 fertB 36-80
"
dt <- setDT(read.table(textConnection(dt), sep = " ", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

# nested data table
nest.dt <- "FIELD_uniqueName OBS_numValue.x OBS_numValue.y
fieldA 5 3
fieldB 4 5
fieldC 7 5
fieldD 5 5
fieldE 4 5
fieldF 4 4
fieldG 5 7
"
nest.dt <- setDT(read.table(textConnection(nest.dt), sep = " ", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

dt$dat <- dt[, list(dat=list(nest.dt))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could loop over the `list` of `data.table` with `lapply`, then within the `data.table` (`x`), create the new columns (`:=`) based on the OP's code

```
library(data.table)
dt[, dat := lapply(dat, function(x)   
         x[, c("n", "vari", "pvalue") := .(.N,  
        var(OBS_numValue.x - OBS_numValue.y), 
           t.test(OBS_numValue.x - OBS_numValue.y, conf.level = 0.90)$p.value)])]
```

-output

```
> dt
   fertName.x YDRange.x fertName.y YDRange.y               dat
1:      fertA     36-80      fertB     36-80 <data.table[7x6]>

> dt$dat[[1]]
   FIELD_uniqueName OBS_numValue.x OBS_numValue.y n     vari pvalue
1:           fieldA              5              3 7 2.333333      1
2:           fieldB              4              5 7 2.333333      1
3:           fieldC              7              5 7 2.333333      1
4:           fieldD              5              5 7 2.333333      1
5:           fieldE              4              5 7 2.333333      1
6:           fieldF              4              4 7 2.333333      1
7:           fieldG              5              7 7 2.333333      1
```

---

If it needs to be separate columns in the `dt`

```
dt[, c("n", "vari", "pvalue") := rbindlist(lapply(dat, function(x) 
     x[, .(.N,  var(OBS_numValue.x - OBS_numValue.y), t.test(OBS_numValue.x - OBS_numValue.y, conf.level = 0.90)$p.value)]))]
```

-output

```
> dt
   fertName.x YDRange.x fertName.y YDRange.y               dat n     vari pvalue
1:      fertA     36-80      fertB     36-80 <data.table[7x3]> 7 2.333333      1
```